# How to get MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService() behavior by using bare ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: guava, executorservice

When I run the following code:

```
package foo.trials;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DirectExecutorService {
    private static final Logger logger_ = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DirectExecutoService.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean useGuava = true;

        final ExecutorService directExecutorService;
        if (useGuava) {
            directExecutorService = MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService();
        } else {
            directExecutorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    0, 1, 0, TimeUnit.DAYS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
                    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
            directExecutorService.submit(new BlockingCallable());
        }

        Future<Boolean> future = directExecutorService.submit(new MyCallable());
        try {
            logger_.info("Result: {}", future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger_.error("Unexpected: Interrupted!", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger_.error("Unexpected: Execution exception!", e);
        }
        logger_.info("Exiting...");
    }

    static class MyCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
        static final Random _random = new Random();
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            logger_.info("In call()");
            return _random.nextBoolean();
        }
    }

    static class BlockingCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {

        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            semaphore.acquire(); // this will never succeed.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
13:36:55.960 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - In call()
13:36:55.962 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Result: true
13:36:55.963 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Exiting...
```

Note that all of the execution happens in the `main` thread.  In particular the callable's call get's dispatched in the calling thread.  Of course, this is what one would expect from `MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()` no surprise there.

And I get similar result when I set the variable `useGuava` to `false`.

```
13:45:14.264 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - In call()
13:45:14.267 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Result: true
13:45:14.268 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Exiting...
```

**But** if I comment out the following line

```
directExecutorService.submit(new BlockingCallable());
```

then I get the following output.

```
13:37:27.355 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - In call()
13:37:27.357 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Result: false
13:37:27.358 [main] INFO  a.t.DirectExecutoService - Exiting...
```

As one can see the callable's call happens in a different thread `pool-1-thread-1`.  I think I can explain why this happens; perhaps because thread pool can have (upto) 1 thread that's available, so the 1st Callable gets dispatched to that extra thread which otherwise was consumed by `BlockingCallable`.

My question is how does one create an `ExecutorService` that'll do what `DirectExecutorService` does without having to artificially burning a thread with a callable that'll never finish?

Why am I asking this?

1. I have a codebase that uses guava at version 11.0.  I'd need to avoid upgrading it to 17.0+ -- which offers `MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()` -- if I can.
2. `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not allow setting `maxThreads` to 0.  It would be odd if it allowed that but if it did then that'd have also solved my problem.
3. Lastly, I was surprised to notice this behavior -- I had assumed (mistakenly) that using `CallerRunsPolicy` would cause all the `call` of **all** `Callable`s to be executed in caller's thread.  So, I wanted to put my experience and hack out there so someone else could save the hours that ended up burning in trying to understand this. :(

Is there better/more idiomatic way to achieve DirectExecutorService like behavior if one can't upgrade to guava 17.0+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there better/more idiomatic way to achieve DirectExecutorService like behavior if one can't upgrade to guava 17.0+?

If that's your only issue here, you should use [`MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/11.0.2/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor()). It's basically [`newDirectExecutorService()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#newDirectExecutorService--) before it was moved to a new method (and [`directExecutor()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor--) was added), see [Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#newDirectExecutorService--):

> Since: 18.0 (present as `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()` since 10.0)

*BTW: You should really upgrade to newest Guava, you're using almost six-year-old one!*

Comment: That's it, thanks!  Point about upgrade is well taken.